# How can I fix "no default secret key" error in GitHub Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to publish a build with a github actions workflow... something I've done numerous times before.  I have secrets set up in github including PGP_PASSPHRASE and PGP_SECRET.

This is all happening server-side on GitHub, so this shouldn't be affected by what I have (or don't have) set up locally, right?

```
[warn] so tooling can use it for eviction errors etc - https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Publishing.html
[info] gpg: no default secret key: No secret key
[info] gpg: signing failed: No secret key
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure running 'gpg --batch --pinentry-mode loopback --passphrase *** --detach-sign --armor --use-agent --output /home/runner/work/scala-reflection/scala-reflection/target/scala-3.3.0/scala-reflection-1.2.2.pom.asc /home/runner/work/scala-reflection/scala-reflection/target/scala-3.3.0/scala-reflection-1.2.2.pom'.  Exit code: 2
[error]     at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:30)
[error]     at com.jsuereth.sbtpgp.CommandLineGpgSigner.sign(PgpSigner.scala:74)
[error]     at com.jsuereth.sbtpgp.PgpSettings$.$anonfun$signingSettings$2(PgpSettings.scala:151)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:293)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map4.foreach(Map.scala:493)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:293)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:290)
[error]     at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:108)
[error]     at com.jsuereth.sbtpgp.PgpSettings$.$anonfun$signingSettings$1(PgpSettings.scala:146)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:68)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:282)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:23)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:291)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:282)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:265)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:64)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
[error] (signedArtifacts) Failure running 'gpg --batch --pinentry-mode loopback --passphrase *** --detach-sign --armor --use-agent --output /home/runner/work/scala-reflection/scala-reflection/target/scala-3.3.0/scala-reflection-1.2.2.pom.asc /home/runner/work/scala-reflection/scala-reflection/target/scala-3.3.0/scala-reflection-1.2.2.pom'.  Exit code: 2
[error] Total time: 17 s, completed Sep 5, 2023 7:45:12 PM

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your agent/runner is missing the secret key. Try to import keys before you run the gpg batch command.